# Drop.levels in a box and whisker plot

Tags: r

I need to use the drop.levels function in my box and whisker plot. The data I'm working with is Dance, the data frames are dance$new and dance$type, the variables I want included are Contra, Blues, and Swing. There are 3 other variables I do not want included; Lindy, Salsa, and Tango.

This is what I have:

```
box.labels<-c("Blues","Contra","Swing")
boxplot(dance$new~dance$type, ylab="Dance Count",
xlab="Type", name=box.labels, drop.levels(Lindy, Salsa, Tango),
main="Dancing for a Healthier You")
```

Am I incorporating drop.levels wrong?

Comment: You should add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for this. We don't know what your data looks like.

Comment: Plus you have not upvoted or accepted or even commented on any answers so far which is considered rude to say the least. Please also read the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) on how to use the site properly.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess, you probably want

```
box.labels<-c("Blues","Contra","Swing")
boxplot(new~type, data=droplevels(subset(dance,type %in% box.labels)),
     ylab="Dance Count",
     xlab="Type", name=box.labels,
     main="Dancing for a Healthier You")
```

The main points here are:

- Both `drop.levels` and `droplevels` are intended for dropping *unused* levels from a data set.  The `subset()` command above is more likely to do what you want.
- I'm using `droplevels()` from base R rather than `gdata::drop.levels`. `droplevels()` is a few years old in base R; `gdata::drop.levels` dates from before it was available).
- I'm using `new~type,data=...` instead of `dance$new~dance$type`; using the `data` argument where possible is generally more readable and more robust.

It's possible that you don't even need `droplevels()`; `boxplot()` might ignore unused levels by default.  The `name` argument might be redundant too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Your tips helped me figure it out.

I ended up plotting subset data which let me avoid the drop levels function. Here is what I used:

```
dancenew<-subset(Dance, Type=="Lindy" | Type== "Blues" | Type=="Contra")

box.labels<-c("Lindy","Blues","Contra") 
boxplot(dancenew$Count~dancenew$Type, ylab="Dance Count", data=ausportnew, xlab="Type", name=box.labels, main="Dancing for a healthier you")
```